Firestore snapshot realtime paging
currently i'm working on a Chat project using ReactJS and Firestore. Let say that i have a subcollection messages which contains multiple docs of message. I have a onSnapshot listener to listen newest message with a limit of 20, which will be discarded on component unmounted.

First question, i want to create a function loadMode() which will assign a new listener on the next 20 documents when user scroll up chat history. The problem is how do i unsubscribe those listeners when i don't need it anymore? Is there any alternative solution here?
Secondly, when i click on other chats and click back to current one, can i cache old message that has been listened to in order to prevent read charge? Does firestore query supports this type of cache or i have to implement it somehow?

Here is what i've tried in code:
//listen to chat
export const useListenChat = (chatId, setMessage) => {
  //register a listener and detach it when component unmounts
  useEffect(() => {
    //initial 5 docs
    const q = query(
      collection(db, `chats/${chatId}/messages`),
      orderBy("sendAt", "desc"),
      limit(5)
    );
    const unSub = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const chats = [];
      querySnapshot.docs.reverse().forEach((doc) => {
        chats.push(doc.data());
      });
      setMessage(chats);
    });

    return () => {
      unSub();
    };
  }, [chatId, setMessage]);
};


export const loadMoreMessages = (
  chatId,
  lastMessageTimestamp,
  setLastMessageTimestamp,
  setMessages,
  setHasMore
) => {
  // Load 20 more messages
  const q = query(
    collection(db, `chats/${chatId}/messages`),
    orderBy("sendAt", "desc"),
    startAfter(lastMessageTimestamp),
    limit(20)
  );
  onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
    const docs = snapshot.docs;
    if (docs.length > 0) {
      // Update the last message timestamp
      setLastMessageTimestamp(docs[docs.length - 1].data().timestamp);
      // Append the new messages to the existing messages
      setMessages([
        ...messages,
        ...docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })),
      ]);
      // There are more messages to load
      setHasMore(true);
    } else {
      setHasMore(false);
    }
  });
};

And i use this in Demo component:
export const Demo = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [lastMessageTimestamp, setLastMessageTimestamp] = useState(null);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const chatId = "example_id";

  useListenChat(chatId, setMessages);
  const loadMore = () => {
    loadMoreMessages(
      chatId,
      lastMessageTimestamp,
      setLastMessageTimestamp,
      setMessages,
      setHasMore
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message) => (
        <div key={message.id}>{message.text}</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={loadMore}>Load more</button>
    </div>
  );
};


The code is working normal, but I don't know whether the listeners on loadMoreMessages function are removed when components unmounted or not.
And when i click others page and get back to this Demo page, old message loaded by loadMoreMessages function are gone.
When i use the onSnapshot on button click while the old one is still exist, will it be a new connection or it will use the current listener?
My goals: cache old message in order to prevent extra read billing charge from firestore || remove listeners to prevent resources leak.
Thanks
Edit 1: I've tried caching by using
initializeFirestore(app, {
  localCache: persistentLocalCache(
    /*settings*/ { tabManager: persistentMultipleTabManager() }
  ),
});

When i see the network tab, no request are made when executing loadMoreMessage

But when i log the fromCache property using
const source = snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local cache" : "server";
    console.log("Data came from " + source);

It still said data came from server

I don't understand why is this opposite


Unsubscribing listeners is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener. If you're having trouble getting this to work, edit your question to show what you tried, what behavior you got, and what you expected/wanted instead.

The caching behavior (and how to enable it for web clients is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline. If that doesn't work for you, once again: show us what you tried.



Hi Frank, i've edited the questions with my code and behaviour
